# JAVA - ¿Cómo paso un array por parámetro en una clase?

Tags: java, array

Tengo que pasar por parámetro del método constructor la matrícula de un coche pero tengo que hacerlo con un array, no puede ser con String. El problema es que a la hora de inicializar el objeto de la clase vehículo, no sé qué tengo que escribir en el parámetro. Creo que tengo que usar un .toCharArray , pero no sé cómo.
[image: Esta imagen es de la clase vehículo con el método constructor]

Luego en la clase principal tengo `Vehiculo v1 = new Vehiculo( *array de matricula* );` y no sé qué tengo que poner en los paréntesis.

Gracias

Comment: Cual es el problema??? Un parámetro de tipo `char[]` guarda una variable de tipo `char[]` sin ningún problema. Y no puedes usar `.toCharArray()` en un array de `char`porque ya es un array de `char`... No veo ningún problema con el código que has mostrado, aunque si lo veo con la pregunta en si misma. Verás, el código es texto y debes tratarlo como tal, no ponernos una imagen de tu código. Si tú ni tes esfuerzas un poquito en seguir las reglas de SO ([ask], [tour]) por qué debemos de esforzarnos nosotros en ayudarte, cuando no ganamos nada haciéndolo?? Pónnoslo un poco fácil, edita la pregunta!

Comment: El código que tienes es correcto. Para llamar al constructor lo puedes hacer así: `Vehiculo v1 = new Vehiculo(new char[] { '1', '2', '3' });`

Answer (score 0):

> Se puede asignar un String a un array de caracteres mediante el método
> toCharArray() de la clase String

```js
import java.util.Arrays;  
public class Vehiculo{
    private double combustible;
    private double km;
    private char matricula[];
    
    public Vehiculo (char [] matricula){
        this.matricula=matricula;
        combustible=0;
    }

public static void main (String[] args) {
  //  asignar  String a un array de caracteres  método toCharArray() de la clase String.
  
String stringMatri="WER1485TY";
char [] matriBMW = stringMatri.toCharArray();  
// OTRA FORMA
char[] matriFord = {'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v'};
 Vehiculo Ford= new Vehiculo(matriFord);  
 Vehiculo BMW= new   Vehiculo(matriBMW);
 

System.out.println("Ford:"+"Matricula"+Arrays.toString(Ford.matricula)+"Combustible:"+Ford.combustible);
System.out.println("BMW:"+"Matricula"+Arrays.toString(BMW.matricula)+"Combustible:"+BMW.combustible);
}
}
```

> De Acuerdo al codigo que mostraste solo para mostrar el paso del
> parametro array de caracteres tenes muchos tutoriales por ejemplo
> [toCharArray()](https://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/10/arrays-de-caracteres-en-java.html) Se puede asignar un String a un array de caracteres mediante el método toCharArray() de la clase String  tambien [tutorial ya JAVA](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/)..Podes ejecutar este
> código en [compilar el codigo](https://onecompiler.com/java/3xm89ftb3)
> Para poder ver la forma de inicializar al array de caracteres recorrerlo y modificarlo [Declarar un array de caracteres en Java](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/java/declare-char-array-java/)...estudiando lo anterior podrás sin problemas divertirte con JAVA